# Setting cache control to private for ALL items

Tags: asp.net, caching, azure, cache-control

I'm about to include this into our build:

```
    void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Cache only on the server and the client (if SSL is disabled)
        // This doesn't determine what should be cached, only where
        // cacheable items are allowed to be stored.
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
    }
```

First off, are my comments in the code correct?

Second, is this an OK action to take? Is it fine to set a cache-control header for all requests? Most my reading, people set cache headers per directory.

I assume this should probably be done in IIS, but we are running in azure so its a little trickier making IIS changes (have to automate it).

Comment: I would think this is a good one for global ability and really just tells it not to cache on a proxy.

Comment: That is my thinking. It would probably bad to set a timeout globally though.

Comment: Definitely since you want certain resources not to timeout, like CSS, JS, images, etc. and if you are integrated pipeline mode it could affect those requests as well.